# LINQ - Returning value of a property of an object that is not null

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects that contain a Person object which may have a null. What I'd like to do is get the value of the Name property of the first Person object that is not null and if all Person objects are null, return an empty string.

My best attempt is as follows:

```
    string userName = MyObjectList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Person != null).Person.Name ?? string.Empty;
```

I think I understand why this doesn't work; if Person is null for each object in my list, then we get the default value, which would be null and will throw a null reference error when I try to access the property Person.

I can get the result I want by checking if any object is not null and then getting the first, but I'd rather accomplish this in one LINQ statement.  Any input is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The usual trick would look something like this:

```
string userName = MyObjectList.Where(x => x.Person != null)
                              .Select(x => x.Person.Name)
                              .FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
```

Or following [*Servy*'s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618104/linq-returning-value-of-a-property-of-an-object-that-is-not-null/20618198?noredirect=1#comment30856641_20618198):

```
string userName = MyObjectList.Where(x => x.Person != null)
                              .Select(x => x.Person.Name)
                              .DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty)
                              .First();
```

---

**Update** it's now relatively easy to do this with C# 6's [null-conditional operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

```
string userName = MyObjectList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Person != null)?.Person.Name ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: You can also use `DefaultIfEmpty` to make it a purely LINQ solution, if you wanted.

Comment: @Servy Good point. I've included a DefaultIfEmpty solution that should work.

Comment: I have below linq query :

var productTypes = from ProductDto e in Product
                                select new 
                                {
                                    Id = e.Product.ID, 
                                    Name = "xyz"
                                };

In above query the e.Product may be null and i am not getting the way,how to add check for this null object.

can you help me out ?

Comment: @Pawan try `from ProductDto e in Product where e.Product != null select new { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

I would do this as two statements:

```
var personContainer = MyObjectList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Person != null);
string userName = personContainer == null ? string.Empty : personContainer.Person.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a null object and trying to read its properties.

Look into something like this:

```
var obj = MyObjectList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Person != null);
string userName = string.Empty;
if (null != obj) {
    userName = obj.Person.Name;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You can check first that you have not null Person:

```
string userName = (MyObjectList.Any((x => x.Person != null))) ? MyObjectList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Person != null).Person.Name : stringEmpty;
```

Comment: This was my initial solution, which works. The accepted solution accomplishes this in a single query.  Thanks for your help though!